# Android: Extract a paused frame from video recorded

Tags: android

I am writing some Android code where I am recording a video, then playing it in videoView and pausing the video. After pausing the video I want to extract the frame that is paused. I know I am supposed to use MediaMetaDataRetiever. But in that we are supposed to use setDataSource(Context c, Uri uri) method. I am unable to figure out how to get context and uri of the video I just recorded.

Comment: Please see: [How do I avoid misusing tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354427/how-do-i-avoid-misusing-tags)

Comment: Incidentally, you *do* know the difference between Android (the operating system) and Android Studio (the IDE), right?